# Do I need to download the entire .NET Framework runtime image when I’m planning to run a console app in a Windows container with AKS?

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, azure-aks

I developed a console application in .NET Framework, and now I want to run it on an AKS cluster. Trying to create the image locally from Docker, I notice that the `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime` is downloading more than 6 GB of stuff: it’s a huge image! Do I really need the .NET Framework runtime to be part of my Docker image, or maybe it's already available when I create a node based on Windows containers?

Comment: The framework is definitely not 6GB. It's around 50MB. That 6GB includes all dependencies, including the operating system. Why are you using .NET Framework though? Why not .NET Core, which was build with containers in mind? You can create a self-contained executable and deploy it on any Linux (or Windows) image without requiring the runtime

Comment: BTW .NET Framework 4.5+ is included in all supported Windows versions so you can argue the actual size is 0. `when I create a node based on Windows containers` running on what host version? If that host doesn't have the correct images the container will have to download them.

Comment: If you check the container's [dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/dd1cda20d1d0ca2f1dd8908efb8891efeb602c20/src/runtime/4.8/windowsservercore-20H2/Dockerfile) in the latest Windows versions you'll see it doesn't include anything, it's just sets some environment variables. In older versions like the original Windows Server Core 2019 [it actually downloads the runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/ee63b25718f434065cd9d1010580ba2a7ab2119f/src/runtime/4.8/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile)

Comment: Because I have to: we have a legacy .NET Framework application that we want to migrate on AKS. The docs say “AKS uses Windows Server 2019 as the host OS version and only supports process isolation. Container images built by using other Windows Server versions are not supported”, so I guess it is used. Moreover, when I move to the node page on the Azure portal, it says only that the operating system is “windows”.